# The constructor of a notifier class is undefined when I try to use it in flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to use a constructor of a notifier but the constructor is "undefined" in the file where I am trying to use it.

Here is the class defined in the provider.dart file:

```
class TrxnNotifier extends Notifier<Trxn> {
    TrxnNotifier.fromFirestore(Map<String, dynamic> firestore)
      : trxnId = firestore['trxnId'],
        userId = firestore['userId'],
        companyId = firestore['companyId'];
}
```

Here is where I am trying to use it in the dashboard.dart file:

```
final trxnStreamProvider = StreamProvider.autoDispose<List<Trxn>>((ref) {
  final stream = firestoreService
      .getCompanyTrxns(ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider).companyId!);

  return stream.map((snapshot) => snapshot.docs.map((doc) => 
      ref.read(trxnNotifierProvider.notifier).fromFirestore(doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>))
      .toList());
});
```

In the dashboard.dart file, I get the error message:
**The method 'fromFirestore' isn't defined for the type 'TrxnNotifier'.**

How do I make this work?
Thanks

**UPDATE:**

I did like you said but now I get this error:

**The name of a constructor must match the name of the enclosing class.dart(invalid_constructor_name)**

Here is what I have for the code now:

```
class TrxnNotifier extends Notifier<Trxn> {

  fromFirestore(Map<String, dynamic> firestore)
      : trxnId = firestore['trxnId'],
        userId = firestore['userId'],
        companyId = firestore['companyId'];
```

I don't have {} around it like you said but I don't know how I would do that.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you have another class also named TrxnNotifier?

Comment: No, I don't. That is the only class named TrxnNotifier.

Comment: Why do you want to build a notifier from firestore? Shouldn't you build a `Trxn` from Firestore, so your notifier can notify about it?

Comment: Thanks for your comment nvoigt. I am new to all of this and I don't understand what you mean. I am wondering if I need the constructor at all. Could I just populate an instance of the Trxn class and pass it to the itemBuilder? I'm not sure how I would do it though.

Answer (score 2):

You are defining `TrxnNotifier.fromFirestore` which is a [named constructor](https://dart.dev/language/constructors#named-constructors). A named constructor is typically called like this:

```dart
TrxnNotifier.fromFirestore(...)
```

What you did was calling `fromFirestore` from `ref.read(trxnNotifierProvider.notifier)` which is an instance of `TrxnNotifier`, not the class itself. If you want to call a method from an instance, define an [instance method](https://dart.dev/language/methods#instance-methods) inside `TrxnNotifier` class like this:

```dart
class TrxnNotifier extends Notifier<Trxn> {
  fromFirestore(Map<String, dynamic> firestore) {
    // implementation
  }
}
```